# "Stale file handle" error, when process trying read the file, that other process already had deleted

Tags: python, linux, nfs

I'm writing stress test suite for testing distributed file systems over NFS.

In some cases when some process deletes file, while some other process attempts to read from it, I'm getting "Stale file handle" error (116).

Is that kind of error is expected and acceptable in such race condition?

Test working as follows:

1. Starting x number of client machines
2. Each client machine runs y processes
3. Each process can do any file operation as stat/read/delete/open
4. Mentioned file ops are standard python methods - os.stat/read/os.remove/open
5. All files are empty 0 bytes data

File is exists, as successful `stat` operation shows:

> controller_debug.log.2:2016-10-26 15:02:30,156;INFO -
> [LG-E27A-LNX:0xa]: finished 640522b4d94c453ea545cb86568320ca, result:
> success | stat |
> /JUyw481MfvsBHOm1KQu7sHRB6ffAXKjwIATlsXmOgWh8XKQaIrPbxLgAo7sucdAM/o6V266xE8bTaUGzk8YDMfDAJp0YIfbT4fIK1oZ2R20tRX3xFCvjISj7WuMEwEV41
> | data: {} | 2016/10/26 15:02:30.156

Process `0x1` on client `CLIENT-A` completed successful delete:

> controller_debug.log.2:2016-10-26 15:02:30,164;INFO -
> [CLIENT-A:0x1]: finished 5f5dfe6a06de495f851745a78857eec1, result:
> success | delete |
> /JUyw481MfvsBHOm1KQu7sHRB6ffAXKjwIATlsXmOgWh8XKQaIrPbxLgAo7sucdAM/o6V266xE8bTaUGzk8YDMfDAJp0YIfbT4fIK1oZ2R20tRX3xFCvjISj7WuMEwEV41
> | data: {} | 2016/10/26 15:02:30.161

3 milliseconds later, process `0xb` on client `CLIENT-B` failed "read" op due to "Stale file handle"

> controller_debug.log.2:2016-10-26 15:02:30,164;INFO -
> [CLIENT-B:0xb]: finished e84e2064ead042099310af1bd44821c0, result:
> failed | read |
> /mnt/DIRSPLIT-node0.b27-1/JUyw481MfvsBHOm1KQu7sHRB6ffAXKjwIATlsXmOgWh8XKQaIrPbxLgAo7sucdAM/o6V266xE8bTaUGzk8YDMfDAJp0YIfbT4fIK1oZ2R20tRX3xFCvjISj7WuMEwEV41
> | [errno:116] | Stale file handle | 142 | data: {} | 2016/10/26
> 15:02:30.160 controller_debug.log.2:2016-10-26 15:02:30,164;ERROR -
> Operation read FAILED UNEXPECTEDLY on File
> JUyw481MfvsBHOm1KQu7sHRB6ffAXKjwIATlsXmOgWh8XKQaIrPbxLgAo7sucdAM/o6V266xE8bTaUGzk8YDMfDAJp0YIfbT4fIK1oZ2R20tRX3xFCvjISj7WuMEwEV41
> due to Stale file handle

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's an acceptable error code given the circumstances (see https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29626, condition 2), but it may not be the only possible response. You'd have to read the specifications and source to know for sure. Can you clarify what, if anything, suggests this may not be an appropriate response?

Comment: @JakeMitchell Thanks for the link Jake. I did know the ESTALE is acceptable for directories, but could find anything about ESTALE on file, and since I'm testing File System under development I can't trust how it handles nfs errors. Do you have links to sources and specs as well?

Comment: Which version of python are you using and how do you start your processes for testing? It might be related to the behavior of `fork` as file descriptors relies on POSIX, which do not allow using forked processes.

Comment: @ThomasMoreau ESTALE errors are errors caused during operations on files via NFS not in the processes itselves

Comment: @Samuel yes but the file descriptors shared for the process operations and the NFS operations. If a fd is closed, it does not matter who try to access it, it should fail.

Comment: @ThomasMoreau So you actually telling the same thing that explained in that link https://access.redhat.com/solutions/29626 isn't it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is totally expected.  The NFS specification is clear about use of file handles after an object (be it file or directory) has been deleted.  [Section 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7530#section-4) clearly addresses this.  For example:

> The persistent filehandle will become stale or invalid when the file system object is removed.  When the server is presented with a persistent filehandle that refers to a deleted object, it MUST return an error of NFS4ERR_STALE.

This is such a common problem, it even has its own entry in section A.10 of the [NFS FAQ](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/), which says one common cause of ESTALE errors is that:

> The file handle refers to a deleted file. After a file is deleted on the server, clients don't find out until they try to access the file with a file handle they had cached from a previous LOOKUP. Using rsync or mv to replace a file while it is in use on another client is a common scenario that results in an ESTALE error.

The expected resolution is that your client app must close and reopen the file to see what has happened.  Or, as the FAQ says:

> ... to recover from an ESTALE error, an application must close the file or directory where the error occurred, and reopen it so the NFS client can resolve the pathname again and retrieve the new file handle.